# Use Automator to read a text file and copy contents to another Folder

Tags: text, automation, applescript, automator

I have a text file that contains the file names of about 500 pictures.

I would like to use Automator to:

1. Read the text file
2. Get a list of the names
3. Look in a 'repository folder' with about 1000 pictures
4. Copy the corresponding picture to a new folder.

Is that possible with Automator on Mac?

Here is what I have attempted, however it doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: Automator is designed for repetitive tasks that do not require decision making.  However, you can add a **Run AppleScript** Action that should do the trick.  If you can post a few details about your 'repository folder,' we can help you craft an AppleScript to solve this.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The repo folder is just a folder on my desktop. It just contains 1000+ pictures.  There are no sub folders.

Comment: What about the destination folder?

Comment: Just another folder on the desktop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the Automator Actions, in order:
[image]

This code inside of the Run AppleScript Action should do the trick:

```
on run {input, parameters}

    set imgDestination to input's item 2
    set imgSource to input's item 1

    set imgNameFile to choose file with prompt {"Select file of image filenames:"}

    set imageList to every paragraph of (read imgNameFile)

    repeat with eachName in imageList
        tell application "Finder"
            set targetImageFile to item 1 of (get every file in folder imgSource whose name = (eachName as text))
            duplicate targetImageFile to folder imgDestination
        end tell
    end repeat
    return input
end run
```

I could not devise how to get Automator to read the text file, and remember it while choosing the folders as well, so I added the choosing of the file with the image filenames as part of the AppleScript.

Good luck,

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much! This really helps out!